# Update table column values based on conditional logic

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have table like this:

```
name | salary 
Tom  | 10000
Mary | 20000
Jack | 30000
Lisa | 40000
Jake | 60000
```

I need an update query to update the salary column depending on the values it contains.

Salaries need to increase by:

- 5000 for values between 10000 to 15000
- 7000 for values between 15000 to 20000
- 8000 for values between 20000 to 30000
- 10000 for values between 40000 to 60000

Comment: You would use a case expression. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using the [CASE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) statement within the [UPDATE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx) command

```
UPDATE
    [yourtablename]
SET
    salary = 
         CASE 
            WHEN salary BETWEEN 10000 AND 15000 THEN salary + 5000 
            WHEN salary BETWEEN 15000 AND 20000 THEN salary + 7000 
            WHEN salary BETWEEN 20000 AND 30000 THEN salary + 8000 
            WHEN salary BETWEEN 40000 AND 60000 THEN salary + 10000 
            ELSE salary
         END
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET salary = CASE 
                    WHEN salary > 10000 AND salary <= 15000 THEN salary + 5000
                    WHEN salary > 15000 AND salary <=20000 THEN salary + 7000
                    .
                    .
                    .
                END
```

Comment: This can be simplified using `salary = salary + CASE` and not including the addition in each individual `WHEN` clause. Or use `salary += CASE`.

Answer (score 2):

Just use an `UPDATE` statement with a `CASE` statement with the required logic in it:

```
UPDATE SalaryTable
SET Salary = 
    (CASE WHEN Salary BETWEEN 10000 AND 14999 THEN Salary + 5000
          WHEN Salary BETWEEN 15000 AND 19999 THEN Salary + 7000
          WHEN Salary BETWEEN 20000 AND 29999 THEN Salary + 8000
          WHEN Salary BETWEEN 40000 AND 59000 THEN Salary + 10000
          ELSE Salary
     END)
```

I've used `BETWEEN` which evaluates **greater than or equal to** and **less than or equal to**, hence the values like `14999`.

Also, you have a gap between `30000` and `40000`, which isn't picked up, but I'm assuming this is down to it being dummy data.

**Reference:**

[SQL BETWEEN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187922.aspx)

[SQL CASE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
UPDATE T
SET T.Salary += CASE
        WHEN T.salary BETWEEN 10000 AND 15000 THEN 5000
        WHEN T.salary BETWEEN 15000 AND 20000 THEN 7000
        WHEN T.salary BETWEEN 20000 AND 30000 THEN 80000
        WHEN T.salary BETWEEN 40000 AND 60000 THEN 10000
        ELSE 0
    END
FROM YourTable AS T
```

Comment: The question states _increase by_, not _replace_. Changing the `=` to `+=` would help, although the default value would have to be `0`.