# sql update multiple rows, with condition in each row

Tags: sql

I have a table with columns A,B,C.

I want to update column C if A and B (A, B together are unique) so the pseudo code looks like this:

```
update table 
set (a = 1, b = 1, c = 1000)
    (a = 2, b = 2, c = 2000)
    (a = 3, b = 3, c = 3000)
where a and b matches columns
```

How can I write this in SQL ?

Comment: You've tagged 3 different RDBMS here and syntax can/does vary from RDBMS to RDBMS. I've removed all the RDBMS tags, however, please amend your question and update the tags to include **only** the RDBMS you are *really* using. Thanks.

Comment: What does "update column C if A and B are unique" mean?  Your question is quite confusing.  If you want to update a single column, why are you setting three values in the `update`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update table column values based on conditional logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28239349/update-table-column-values-based-on-conditional-logic)

Answer (score 2):

Multiple updates works in any RDBMS

```
update yourtable set c = 1000 where a = 1 and b = 1
update yourtable set c = 2000 where a = 2 and b = 2
update yourtable set c = 3000 where a = 3 and b = 3
```

One would assume that the UPDATE statement should be quite standard.
But when updating from tables or sub-queries there can be differences in the syntax.

This works in MS Sql Server

```
update t
set c = q.c
from yourtable t
join (values 
   (1, 1, 1000)
  ,(2, 2, 2000)
  ,(3, 3, 3000)
) q(a, b, c)
on t.a = q.a and t.b = q.b
```

This works in Postgresql

```
update yourtable t
set c = q.c
from 
(values 
   (1, 1, 1000)
  ,(2, 2, 2000)
  ,(3, 3, 3000)
) q(a, b, c)
where q.a = t.a and q.b = t.b
```

This works in MySql

```
update yourtable t
join 
(
   select 1 as a, 1 as b, 1000 as c
   union all select 2, 2, 2000
   union all select 3, 3, 3000
) q on q.a = t.a and q.b = t.b
set t.c = q.c
```

This works in the Oracle RDBMS

```
update yourtable t 
set t.c = 
(
   select q.c
   from 
   (
      select 1 as a, 1 as b, 1000 as c from dual
      union all select 2, 2, 2000 from dual
      union all select 3, 3, 3000 from dual
   ) q
   where q.a = t.a and q.b = t.b
)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use a `case` expression:

```
update table 
    set c = (case when a = 1 and b = 1 then 1000
                  when a = 2 and b = 2 then 2000
                  when a = 3 and b = 3 then 3000
             end)
where (a = 1 and b = 1) or (a = 2 and b = 2) or (a = 3 and b = 3);
```

Comment: @forpas . . . The typo has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean when `a` is equal to `b`:

```
UPDATE t 
SET c = 1000 * a
WHERE a = b;
```

for any rdbms.
See [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oYcRQ8CVucz7jMb9gWXVVJ/0)